# Pandas pivot table gives "FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned"

Tags: python, pandas, warnings, concatenation

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'category':['A', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 
                   'bar':[2, 5, float('nan'), float('nan')]})
```

And then I have just one line of code, where I'm trying to apply two aggregation functions on a column in my DataFrame, grouped by values in another column:

```
df.pivot_table('bar', 'category', aggfunc=['median', 'count'])
```

For some reason, it gives me the following warning:

> FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned.
>   A future version of pandas will change to not sort by default. To
>   accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'. To retain the current
>   behavior and silence the warning, pass 'sort=True'.

From what I can understand about this warning, it concerns "concat()" or "append()" methods. I called neither of these, so I can only assume that one of the two is used implicitly somewhere inside the "pivot_table()" method. I'd be happy to pass the "sort" parameter to silence the warning, but I don't see the way of doing that if the method is called implicitly.

I ran some tests on this example, and it looks like the warning appears only when all three of the following conditions are met:

1) there's at least one group in the values that get aggregated that consists entirely of missing values;

2) there are at least two aggregation functions;

3) one of the aggregation functions is "count()".

My working theory at the moment is that the two aggregation functions can't agree on how many rows the resulting pivot table should have. The "count()" function puts zeroes in all groups that consist entirely of missing values. But the other functions ignore such groups entirely, so the respective rows are simply missing from the pivot table when "count()" is not present. However, when "count()" is present, it forces the other functions to not ignore these groups, and creates NaN values in respective cells.

This result works fine for me, I can use it, but I don't like leaving warnings unattended. Thoughts on what can be done about it?

Comment: What is your pandas version? can you post some sample data? My guess is that it is related to `median` as to get this value, the dataframe must be sorted, I know there were some problems in early versions of pandas.

Comment: @jcaliz My pandas version is 0.25.1. I heard that pandas got a 1.0 release recently, but the "conda update conda" command didn't seem to change that version in my Jupyter, and "conda update pandas" produces the message "All requested packages already installed." As for sample data, I've experimented on the issue some more and updated the post accordingly, please take a look.

Comment: Can you post some sample data? Maybe just a couple of rows to see if anybody can replicate the issue. It is always better to have a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @jcaliz But I just did yesterday! Check my original post, I added the reproducible example right there (or refresh the page, if it's already open). Though I'm beginning to suspect that I can already guess the solution - filtering out empty groups before applying pivot_table(). Unless you know a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate the issue on pandas 0.25.1, the waning is related to `pandas.core.reshape.pivot.py` that includes the following statement

```
# line 56
return concat(pieces, keys=keys, axis=1)
```

Concat is causing the warning. `pieces` is a list of dataframes where each elemenet is related to each function from the parameter `aggfunc`, what happens is the following:

```
pieces[0]
#           bar
# category     
# A         2.0
# B         5.0

pieces[1]
#           bar
# category     
# A           1
# B           1
# C           0
```

Since `pieces[0]` and `pieces[1]` have a different index, pandas needs to sort the dataframes to match between the values.

This issue does not happen in `1.0.1`. If you don't want the warning to show, add parameter `dropna=False` so the `NaN`-columns are all included in the aggfunction.

```
df.pivot_table('bar', 'category', aggfunc=['median', 'count'], dropna=False)
```

Be careful, some funciones are not meant to be used with nan values, numpy inlcudes al lot of functions that handles `nan` like [`np.nanmedian`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmedian.html) and [`np.nanmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmax.html) consider checking those out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the upvote, now I finally got voting rights myself :)

Adding "dropna=False" solves the issue for this reproducible example. But I discovered something weird when I tried to add this parameter to the original DataFrame: now it causes the error "'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'". And when I tried to make a reproducible example for that, turns out that the same DataFrame as in this question along with the command "df.pivot_table('bar', 'category', aggfunc='size')" - regardless of "dropna" parameter, causes the exact same error. Should I create a separate question?

Comment: Yes, it is better to create a separate question with the reproducible example.

Comment: [Done!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61465116/pandas-pivot-table-aggregation-with-size-gives-an-error-series-object-has-n)

Answer (score 0):

The solution of **jcaliz** is the right one, but I ended up simply filtering the DataFrame before applying "pivot_table()". In my case I also wanted to get sizes of groups, so simply filtering the NaN values directly would not be what I want. I ended up doing this:

```
not_na = df.groupby('category')['bar'].count()
not_na = not_na[not_na > 0]
pivot = df[df['category'].isin(not_na.index)].pivot_table('bar', 'category', aggfunc=['median', 'size'])
pivot['count'] = not_na
```