# Pandas pivot table aggregation with 'size' gives an error "'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'"

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, attributeerror

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1, 3, 3, 4],
                   'bar': [2, 5, 8, 9],
                   'abc': [3, 7, 2, 4]})
```

When I tried using the command:

```
df.pivot_table('bar', 'foo', aggfunc='size')
```

I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'

Strangely, the problem disappears when I aggregate several columns simultaneously:

```
df.pivot_table(['bar', 'abc'], 'foo', aggfunc='size')
```

But reappears again if I add the "dropna=False" parameter:

```
df.pivot_table(['bar', 'abc'], 'foo', aggfunc='size', dropna=False)
```

Expected output (that I do successfully get with the second command):

```
foo
1    1
3    2
4    1
dtype: int64
```

By the way, I'm using 'size' instead of 'count' on purpose, as I want to know the group sizes *including* the NaN values (even though it's not shown in this minimal example, because apparently the presence of NaNs is not necessary to trigger the error).

My version of pandas is 0.25.1. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: do you want 'bar' like values and 'foo' like index? 
what data frame do you expect as a result?

Comment: @ansev Yes, 'bar' like values and 'foo' like index. The order of arguments is correct though. It's equivalent to _values='bar', index='foo'_, and the "columns" parameter is missing on purpose.

Comment: I understand that size must be used with columns and index or multiIndex in index or columns, I think it is necessary to calculate the size that there are two axes

Comment: @ansev How do I get the size of a Series then? [Series.size](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.size.html) seems to exist.